# ReactJS onClick not working - nothing happends in the browser and in the system console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onclick

I've read a lot of threads about this problem, but still I can't fix it.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react/addons');

var SegmentComponent = React.createClass({

    handleThatEvent: function (e)
    {
        console.log('clicked');
    },

    render: function ()
    {
        const styles = {
            left: this.props.leftPercent + '%',
            width: this.props.widthPercent + '%'
        };

        if (this.props.color !== undefined)
        {
            styles.backgroundColor = this.props.color;
        }

        return (
            <span onClick={this.handleThatEvent()} style={styles} className="track-notation"></span>
        )
    }
});

module.exports = SegmentComponent;
```

When I click on **span** nothing happends. I'm new in ReactJS, so maybe I missed an obvious thing.

There is not a "clicked" text in the web browser console and in the system console (Terminal).

**EDIT:**

I tried with

```
onClick={this.handleThatEvent.bind(this)}
```

and

```
{() => this.handleThatEvent()}
```

and is still nothing.

Also in HTML there isn't onClick attribute in span element:

```
<span style="left:10%;width:10%;" class="track-notation" data-reactid=".rru3h8zkm2.1:0.0.2.0"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 onClick={this.handleThatEvent()}
```

replace with

```
  onClick={this.handleThatEvent}
```

Comment: It's not working. "onClick" attribute is not in the span element

Comment: Simon have your read the react docs for events? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html. onClick is react it will never be in the span element, onClick doesn't exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Careful you've passed `this.handleThatEvent()` into `onClick` event, and executed it there, you need to pass only the function `this.handleThatEvent` on `onClick` will execute it... see:

```js
const SegmentComponent = React.createClass({
  handleThatEvent: function (e) {
    console.log('clicked');
  },
  render: function () {
    const styles = {
      left  : this.props.leftPercent + '%',
      width : this.props.widthPercent + '%'
    };
    if (this.props.color !== undefined) {
      styles.backgroundColor = this.props.color;
    }
    return (
      <span
        onClick={this.handleThatEvent}
        style={styles}
        className="track-notation"
      >Click me!
      </span>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <SegmentComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I've added live working example... then you have different problem

Comment: @Simon perhaps you don't use Javascript compiler. like Babel

Answer (score 0):

that's the problem:

```
onClick={this.handleThatEvent()}
```

should be like that:

```
onClick={this.handleThatEvent.bind(this)}
```

or

```
 onClick={() => this.handleThatEvent()}
```

Comment: React.creatClass does auto binding

Comment: @Simon can you please try this: onclick='handleThatEvent()'.. not sure.. or onclick='handleThatEvent' ... or try to add a <button onClick={this.props.handleThatEvent} > around it... is working with a button?